# Regex function to find all and only 6 digit numeric string ignoring spaces if any any between

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have HTML source page as text file.

I need to read file and find out only those numeric strings which have 6 continous digits and can have a space in between those 6 digits

Eg

1. `209 016` -  should be come up  in search result and as `400013`(space removed)
2. `209016` - should also come up  in search and unaltered as `209016`
3. any numeric string more then 6 digits long should not come up in search eg `20901677`,`209016@223`, `29016`,

I  think this  can be achieved by regex but  I  was  not  able  to

A soln in regex is more desirable  but  anything else is  also  welcome

Comment: Why shouldn't `209016@223` result in the match `209016`? What are the relevant boundaries that separate numbers (since spaces don't seem to apply)? Perhaps any non-digit non-space character? Another question is, should `123 456 789` be matched and if so, what should the result be? `123456` or `456789` or none of them or both (actually then also `234567`, `345678` should match)?

Answer (score 2):

To match 6 digits with any number of spaces in between, you may use the following pattern:

```
\b(?:\d[ ]*?){6}\b
```

Or if you want to reject it when it's followed by an `@`, you may use:

```
\b(?:\d[ ]*?){6}\b(?!@)
```

**[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DEwJaG/1)**.

Then, you can use the `replace` method to remove the space characters.

**Python example:**

```
import re

regex = r"\b(?:\d[ ]*?){6}\b(?!@)"

test_str = ("209016 \n"
    "209 016\n"
    "20901677','209016@223', '29016")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for match in matches:
    print (match.group().replace(" ", ""))
```

**Output:**

```
209016
209016
```

**[Try it online](https://rextester.com/FEPV94446)**.

Comment: You regex is really good I would recommend to change it into:
`\b(?:\d\s*?){6}\b(?!@)` otherwise you might end up having many spaces taken into the result string at the end for example for : `123456              `

Comment: @Allan That's a good idea. Although it wouldn't affect the final output since all space characters will be removed anyway.

Comment: Also you need to put the same logic with the `@` at the beginning I guess `\b(?<!@)...` imagine you have `209016@223123` in the text! Anyway +1 ;-)

Comment: This matches `209016!223` for example and I hardly think this is what OP wants. Also why not just do `test_str.replace(' ', ''`) and then use a regex without `\s`?

Comment: Yeah I completely agree the question is not clear...

Comment: Thanks a lot , the suggestions seems to  work for me :)

Comment: @RahulSingh: you are welcome! Could you please accept either Ahmed or my answer? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following regex:

```
\b(?<!@)\d(?:\s*\d){5}\b(?!@)
```

demo: https://regex101.com/r/ZCcDmF/2/

But note that you might have to modify your boundaries if you need to exclude more than the `@`. it will become something like:

```
\b(?<!@|other char I need to exclude|another one|...)\d(?:\s*\d){5}\b(?!@|other char I need to exclude|another one|...)
```

where you have to replace `other char I need to exclude`, `another one`,... by the characters.